# Showing user's information on the ListView one after another

Tags: java, android, android-listview

**Problem Statement:-**

In my below code, I am getting `list of User's` which I am showing currently on the `google map` which is working fine for me. And also I need to show them on the `ListView` which is not working correctly.

So currently I have list of `two user's in the response`. And if I try to print them in the `for loop`, I can see both of the user getting printed correctly. But when I try to add them in my `ListView`, I see `only one user` getting shown on the `ListView twice`? But I should be seeing both the user one after another on the `ListView`.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<User> response) {

    for(User user : response){

        System.out.println("User:- " +user.getFirstName());

// Something wrong I am doing in below line
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(ThesisProjectAndroid.this, mStrings, user);

        if(user.getGender()==1) {
            Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.current_user);
            int markerWidth = marker.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int markerHeight = marker.getIntrinsicHeight();
            marker.setBounds(0, 0, markerHeight, markerWidth);


            myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker);
            mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);

            GeoPoint myPoint1 = new GeoPoint((int) (user.getLatitude()*1000000), (int) (user.getLongitude()*1000000));
            myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint1, "myPoint1", "myPoint1");
        } else {

            Drawable marker1=getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
            int markerWidth1 = marker1.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int markerHeight1 = marker1.getIntrinsicHeight();
            marker1.setBounds(0, 0, markerHeight1, markerWidth1);


            myItemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(marker1);
            mapView.getOverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);

            GeoPoint myPoint2 = new GeoPoint((int) (user.getLatitude()*1000000), (int) (user.getLongitude()*1000000));
            myItemizedOverlay.addItem(myPoint2, "myPoint2", "myPoint2");
        }

    }
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And this is my `LazyAdapter class`.

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private User userList;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public LazyAdapter(Activity b, String[] mStrings, User user) {
        activity = b;
        data=mStrings;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        userList = user;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        TextView text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text.setText("Name: " +userList.getFirstName()+" "+userList.getLastName());
        text1.setText("Gender: " +userList.getGender());
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

And this is the XML for showing `user's list`- I need to show `User's Full Name` on one `TextView` and `Gender` on second `TextView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="50dip"
      android:layout_height="50dip" android:src="@drawable/stub" android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is what I am getting in my Emulator- One User showing twice in my listview why is it so? But it should be `One user information` at the `top` and `second user information` below that.

Comment: Your `userList` variable that you use on every item in the list represents only a single user. You need some list of users there (the complete `response` you get in `onPostExecute`).

Comment: Can you show me an example how this will work as you said just now. By that I can understand it very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the complete list of users to your adapter

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<User> response) {

    // add all users to the adapter
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(ThesisProjectAndroid.this, mStrings, response);

    for(User user : response){

        System.out.println("User:- " +user.getFirstName());

        // ---- here be ur other code ----
    }
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Your Adapter

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private List<User> userList;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public LazyAdapter(Activity b, String[] mStrings, List<User> user) {
        activity = b;
        data=mStrings;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        userList = user;
    }

    // ---- here be ur other code ----

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        TextView text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text.setText("Name: " +userList.get(position).getFirstName()+" "+userList.get(position).getLastName());
        text1.setText("Gender: " +userList.get(position).getGender());
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```